# How to call event from checkbox element only if checkbox is checked

Tags: angularjs

Here is my rows code:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {       
       $scope.foo = function() {
         alert("bla bla bla");
       };
    }]);
```

```css
#rollDiv {
    margin:4px;
    background-color:#EFEFEF;
    border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #D0D0D0;
    overflow:auto;
    float:left;
}

#rollDiv label span { 
    padding:5px 5px 2px 2px;
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl">

<label>
<input type='checkbox' ng-click='foo()' hidden><span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span>
</label>

</div>
```

At the example above `foo` event is fired when element checked and unchecked, can I make a call of the event from checkbox element only if checkbox is checked and event not called if I uncheck element.I don't feel like making any changes in controller.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you are looking for.

```
<input type='checkbox' ng-model='chkMonitor'  ng-click='chkMonitor && foo()'>
```

`chkMonitor` is just a simple scope variable.

Explanation:

`foo()` function can be conditionally executed by placing it in a boolean expression. The following ...

```
ng-click='false && foo()'
```

will never execute the function. So, the task is to replace `false` with a variable which represent the check state. We can use `$event.target.checked` - but DOM referencing in angular expression is prohibited.

Solution is to bind a scope variable with the check box and use it with `foo()`

---

Of course there are conventional methods which can filter out clicks inside the `foo()` function. But your question was about NOT firing `foo()` if not checked.

Comment: I swapped ng-click to ng-change as a bit more robust, catching more scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Look this:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('Ctrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.foo = function() {
        console.log("bla bla bla");
      };
    }
  ]);
```

```css
#rollDiv {
  margin: 4px;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
  overflow: auto;
  float: left;
}
#rollDiv label span {
  padding: 5px 5px 2px 2px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl">

  <label>
    <input type='checkbox' ng-model="cbxTest" ng-click='read?"":foo();read=true' hidden><span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span>
  </label>

</div>
```